# Facebook login on iPhone thowing errors

Tags: ios, facebook, mobile-website

I have seen several past questions in SO, but none of them see to answer the question.

I am trying to have my iphone webapp use the Facebook login, but it fails everytime with a 191 error:
An error occurred with My Dev app. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

My FB logging link looks like such:

`http://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?scope=email,user_birthday&client_id=1754645158****&redirect_uri=http://dev.someDomain.com&display=touch`

Post trying to following the link the return uri is stripped from the url:

`http://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?scope=email,user_birthday&client_id=1754645158*****&redirect_uri=&display=touch`

Per the fb dev site when specifying the domain:
If set, Facebook will enable authentication on all subdomains (e.g., "example.com" will enable *.example.com)

when I change it to my main domain, it redirects correctly.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I figured it out, adding www: 
`redirect_uri=http://www.dev.some`

instead of:
`redirect_uri=http://dev.some`

Seems to fix this, now to finish the rest of the login...